# How to include varying count of variables into a sql IN statement?

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

I have a number of variables (count varies each time script is executed). I need to insert these variables into a sql statement. For example, let us assume the sql statement to be:

```
select * from customer where customer_id in (...);
```

What comes in those dotted lines will be my variables. If I knew the count of variables, I could have done something like:

```
query='''create table xyz as 
         select * from customer where customer_id in (?,?);'''
cursor.execute(query,var1,var2)
query='select * from xyz;'
xyz_details=pd.read_sql(query,con)
```

But since the count varies, I cannot keep a fixed number of '?' in my query. It could be 2 in one run and 4 in another. The script does store the count in a variable 'cnt'. So if cnt is 4, i have `var1,var2,var3,var4` as arguments, and i will need to have 4 '?' in my query.

However, since these counts keep changing, I cannot fix a definite value in my query and I am looking on how to proceed.

Any comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like that ?

```
list_args = [var1, var2, ..., varn]
query='''create table xyz as 
         select * from customer where customer_id in ({});'''.format(','.join('?' * len(list_args)))
cursor.execute(query,var1,var2)
query='select * from xyz;'
xyz_details=pd.read_sql(query,con)
```